# Footnote distance from bodytext in ConTeXt

Tags: footnotes, context

I removed the footnote line separator using this:
`\unexpanded\def\mehrule{\blackrule[length=0pt,color=black,height=0pt,depth=0pt]}`

But the whitespace between footnote block and text block appeared to be a bit too much.

Is there a way to fiddle with distance between them in ConTeXt? Thanks in advance for any help from ConTeXt magicians here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ConTeXt defaults to inserting a `\blank` before every footnote placement; you can disable this by setting the `before` key of `\setupfootnotes` to something empty:

<sub>*(skip past the irrelevant setup code to the demonstration at the end)*</sub>

```tex
%%% Begin irrelevant setup code
\setuppapersize[A7, landscape][A4, portrait]
\setuppaper[nx=2,ny=4]
\setuparranging[XY]

\setuppagenumbering[state=stop]
\setupindenting[3em, yes]
\setupbodyfont[11pt]

\startsetups[*default]
    \directsetup{*reset}
    \clubpenalty=0
    \widowpenalty=0
    \parskip=0pt plus 1fil
\stopsetups

\define[1]\samples{
    \noindent\bold{#1:}
    \dorecurse{4}{
        \dorecurse{20}{
            \convertnumber{words}{\recurselevel}
        }
        \footnote{footnote}
        \par
    }
    \vfill
    \page
}

\setupbackgrounds[text][
    frame=on,
    framecolor=lightgray,
]

\setupfootnotes[
    topframe=on,
    framecolor=lightgray,
]
%%% End irrelevant setup code

%%% Demonstration:
\starttext
    \samples{Default}


    \setupfootnotes[
        before={},
    ]
    \samples{No space}


    \setupfootnotes[
        before={},
        rule=off,
    ]
    \samples{No space, no rule}


    \setupfootnotes[
        before={\blank[2*line]},
        rule=normal,
    ]
    \samples{Extra space}
\stoptext
```

[image: output]

Comment: It works like a charm, thanks. Where did you get all knowledge of ConTeXt to such a great detail?

Comment: @MuhammadRizqiSiregar For this specifically: you can remove the space before most ConTeXt commands with `\setupXXX[before={}]`, and the rule stuff I got [from the Wiki page](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupfootnotes). In general, reading through [the mailing list](https://mailman.ntg.nl/archives/list/ntg-context@ntg.nl/latest), [the wiki](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Main_Page), [the manuals](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Documentation), and [the source](https://github.com/contextgarden/context).